# Difficulty Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a game where users can upload levels, and I was attempting to rank/sort them by how difficult they where.

I was wondering if anyone was aware of any algorithms based on wins/losses to determine difficulty that might exist. I know mario maker bases their difficulty on the number of users that beat a level, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about determining difficulty.

I just wasn't sure what would be a fair measurement of difficulty for a level.

Comment: Difficulty is subjective and not really possible to determine by calculation, have you ever played a procedurally generate game where later levels(supposedly harder) can be much easier? Of course. I think pass rates is a suitable substitute

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article which presents an interesting algorithm to sort items by their rating (in this case the rating would be the pass rate). It tries to account for the uncertainty presented by low sample sizes so that, in your case, a level with 1 loss and 0 wins is not regarded as harder than a level with 100 losses and 1 win.

The article: https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Let me know if you need any more clarification!